# for loop (i) variable used outside the loop or possible solution?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, for-loop, awt

I am trying to find a way for my startTextFieldListener to gain access to some variables in my for loop. Is there a way to do this? I'm sorry if there is an easy solution to this but I am not quite sure how to work around this. I have seen some examples but I did not know how to apply it to my program. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class TextArea1{

JTextArea text;
JFrame frame;
JTextField textField;
public int k;
public ArrayList aList;
public String correctAnswer;

public static void main (String [] args) {
    TextArea1 gui = new TextArea1();

    gui.go();
}
private String textLine;

public void go() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    textField = new JTextField("");
    textField.addActionListener(new startTextFieldListener(aList));
    JButton startButton  = new JButton ("Start!");
    startButton.addActionListener(new startButtonListener(aList));


    text = new JTextArea (30, 60);
    text.setLineWrap(true);

    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(text);
    scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    panel.add(scroller);

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, startButton);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, textField);      
    frame.setSize(350, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}       



class startButtonListener implements ActionListener {
 ArrayList aList;
 startButtonListener(ArrayList passedInList)
 {
      aList = passedInList;
 }

 @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
     String fileName = "test.txt";
    String line;
    ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();

    try {
         try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(fileName))) {
             if (!input.ready())   {
                 throw new IOException();

             }

             while ((line = input.readLine()) !=null) {
                 aList.add(line);
             }}
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);

    }

    int sz = aList.size();

       for (int k = 0; k< sz; k++) {          

        String correctAnswer = aList.get(k).toString();

    text.append(aList.get(k).toString());
    text.append("\n");
       }   
}
}       
    class startTextFieldListener implements ActionListener {
         startTextFieldListener(ArrayList passedInList)
         {
             aList = passedInList;
         }




         @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            text.getText();
             if (text.getText().equals(correctAnswer)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hooray!");
             }

             else if (!text.getText().equals(correctAnswer)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong!");


             }

            }



             }
        }
```

Comment: dont get your point doing that.. what result do you expected?

Comment: When you use `i` in your listener, what value are you expecting it to be?

Comment: Use instance variables?

Comment: Looking at this again, it would not even work right? I wanted to check if the textField is the same as the correctAnswer string. I'm not sure how to have this work in two different listeners but is there a way to have both a text field and a textarea together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could attempt to do this by trying to make the variables accessible to the entire class.

To implement this, you can add the variable declaration where you have declared your User Interface items, after the class declaration.

You could then access this variable in another class.

Example Code:

```
public class TextArea1{

JTextArea text;
JFrame frame;
JTextField textField;

public int sampleIntToBeUsed;
```

You could also implement this with various get/set methods.

How to Make a Constructor: (Put the name of the class with no return type)

```
class startButtonListener implements ActionListener {
     ArrayList aList;
     startButtonListener(ArrayList passedInList)
     {
          aList = passedInList;
     }
```

New Second ActionListener

```
class startTextFieldListener implements ActionListener {
     String correctAnswer;
     startTextFieldListener(String answer)
     {
         correctAnswer = answer;
     }

         @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
             if (text.getText().equals(correctAnswer)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hooray!");
             }

             else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong!");
             }

          }
     }
    }
```

Comment: I believe OP is referring to `i` variable, which belongs to the `for` loop

Comment: Yes, but instead of using i, the loop can use sampleIntToBeUsed.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I've changed (i) but now the aList variable comes underlined. Would you know how to fix that? I have tried making the array public too but it did not allow me to use toString() due to "not allowed to use void).

Comment: Can you revise the code in the question? (If you post the updated code I may be able to help)

Comment: Ok, in the listener classes, I would add a constructor that takes the aList as a parameter. Then set ArrayList aList = passedInList; in the listener classes. Does this help?

Comment: I hate to say it but I'm very confused. I'm not sure how to properly make the constructor. Sorry but if it's not to much hassle, could you show me? I will promise to leave you alone after this.

Comment: I did put that code in but I am seeing the same error. I will edit my post showing the current code. Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: Your welcome. Please post the code and I will try to help you debug it.

Comment: Updated. Also I now have error messages relating to (new startTextFieldListener and new startButtonListener. Perhaps I didn't do something with the constructor

Comment: Yes, you now have to pass in aList, so the line textField.addActionListener(new startTextFieldListener()); should be textField.addActionListener(new startTextFieldListener(aList)); Did this help? (and the same goes for the creation of the other listener)

Comment: Yes, the errors have gone now. However, pressing enter does not do anything right now, so I can't compare the strings. Do you know how to do that? **in the second action listener

Comment: To compare Strings, I would use stringName.equals(string2); If the string is part of the Array List, then you would do aList.get(i).equals("something"); Did this help?

Comment: Ok, I think I know what you are trying to do: try substituting text.append.get(k).toString())) for just text.getText(); Does this resolve the problem?

Comment: Here is the most recent version. Please take a look if you can. If you cannot figure it out, it is fine. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer with the new second listener class. Now, when you use this, you will have to pass in the correct answer in the main class as a string, not the aList. So replace     textField.addActionListener(new startTextFieldListener(aList));
with textField.addActionListener(new startTextFieldListener("correct answer")); Does this help?

Comment: Yes, the message is now displaying. However, the intention was to have it so that after each line it would check if that line was correct or wrong. Do you know what it is exactly checking for, for the correctAnswer?

Comment: The correctAnswer is checking the contents of the JTextArea, it is a string, so you can set the value to what ever you would like. If my answer has helped you solve this question, please don't forget to click the check next to the up vote button on the answer, this way visitors to the page will know that this answer was helpful to you.

Comment: I see. I have lowered the txt document to one line and copied it exactly the same but it the it still showed "Wrong!". Do you know why this is?

Comment: At this point, as the discussion has moved from the original topic, it may be best to create a new thread with all of your updated code and new question, so it is less confusing. Feel free to post the link to the new thread here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284722/jtextarea-arraylist-string-data-and-jtextfield-input-data-not-matching